# How to detect if text contains [FSI]*[PDI]

Tags: java, android, unicode, bidi

Android Studio logcat for incoming notification message show like this **[]message[]** .

I copy and paste to .txt file, it show **FSImessagePDI** .

[image]

What is this kind of character "FSI" & "PDI" ? And how can I detect when the text contains them?

Comment: These are special character types used for bidirectional text. How do you want to detect them? If they are present in a String in Java?

Comment: @Matt, in whatsapp group chat, when someone mention you as @, the content notification will show []Matt[].  I would like to detect whenever someone mentioned me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are special unicode characters used for bidirectional text and part of the group *Explicit Directional Isolate Formatting Characters*. They are used in your example to easily insert a text-fragment with unknown direction. This can be done by wrapping the fragment in FSI and PDI. Consult [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/) for more information.

To detect them, we need to know their unicode representation:

- First Strong Isolate (FSI) represented by `0x2068` (UTF-16).
- Pop Directional Isolate (PDI) represented by `0x2069` (UTF-16).

Now we can use the regex `\u2068(.*?)\u2069` to extract the wrapped content:

```java
String input = "Hi \u2068Bob\u2069!\nHow is \u2068Alice\u2069?";
System.out.println(input);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\u2068(.*?)\u2069");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

*Output:*
[image: output]

Comment: can you please update the answer for a method that return true/false when detect text is FSI/PDI instead extract the wrapped content. Thank you.

Comment: @CauCuKien You can just leave out the while-loop if you don't need the contents. `m.find()` returns *true* if something was found and *false* if not.